# Where does backtick and single quote come from when denoting commands e.g. `prog'?

Tags: shell, history, programming

When referring to commands in tutorials, man pages, and articles I see authors use the backtick and single quote in this way:

```
`./configure'
`make'
```

I believe I have seen gcc denote points of failure during compilation with that sequence.
Where does it come from and why do many people use it as a convention for commands to issue?

Comment: See also the similar [Where does this convention for quotation marks (`` …'') come from? [closed\]](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85303/where-does-this-convention-for-quotation-marks-come-from).

Comment: see [Why do Unix man pages use double backticks in place of double quotes?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73989/why-do-unix-man-pages-use-double-backticks-in-place-of-double-quotes/73996)