# Why bash encapsulates syntax error both with grave accent and with an apostrophe?

Tags: bash

When bash is reporting a syntax error, it encapsulates the text which has raised the syntax error both with grave accent and with an apostrophe, like this: `` `...' ``. Any idea why?

Here's an example:

```
$ bash -c "echo error()"
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `echo error()'
```

This is not very common; however, I am just curious, this is not a real problem.

**Edit:** this gets weirder with obscure messages like this one:

```
-bash: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
```

Comment: May have common roots with [Where does backtick and single quote come from when denoting commands e.g. `prog'? [duplicate\]](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87644/where-does-backtick-and-single-quote-come-from-when-denoting-commands-e-g-prog).

Comment: The answer is here: "[Why do Unix man pages use double backticks in place of double quotes?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73989/why-do-unix-man-pages-use-double-backticks-in-place-of-double-quotes)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In certain fonts, those quotation marks will appear as opposing pairs of curled single quotes. It's *passé* in [today's Unicode world](https://www.stone.com/The_Cocoa_Files/Smart_Quotes.html), but the code and practices that produced such quoting derive from a time before Unicode, or before its widespread availability.

Comment: More than one could possibly wish to know on the topic: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html

Comment: +1 for using "passe'" in a technical answer. Bravo, sir!